# When Bootstrap button is clicked it changes to primary state

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, button

This question might seem to be a duplicate, but the other solutions are not working for me.

My problem is whenever I click my customized Bootstrap button it changes to the btn-primary style.

**Customized button:**

[image]

**Button clicked:**

[image]

When I search for a solution, I only find them with `btn:active:focus`.
I've tried this but it didn't do the trick for me.

**My CSS:**

```
.btn-custom01 {
    background-color:#3b3b3b;
    border-color:#ff0066;
}
.btn-custom01:active:focus{background-color:#333333; border-color:#ff0066; color:#ff0066; }
.btn-custom01:hover{background-color:#3b3b3b; border-color:#f2f2f2;}
```

How do I fix this? I hope someone here can help me out.

Comment: Have you tried them separately? I mean: .btn-custom01:active:{background-color:#333333; border-color:#ff0066; color:#ff0066; } .btn-custom01:focus{background-color:#333333; border-color:#ff0066; color:#ff0066; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're chaining your element state, remove active from the chain and focus starts working. If you want both, separate them differently.

```css
.btn-custom01 {
  background-color: #3b3b3b;
  border-color: #ff0066;
}

.btn-custom01:focus {
  background-color: #333333;
  border-color: #ff0066;
  color: #ff0066;
}

.btn-custom01:hover {
  background-color: #3b3b3b;
  border-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button class='btn btn-custom01'>Hello World</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.btn-custom01:focus`

```
.btn-custom01 {
  background-color: #3b3b3b;
  border-color: #ff0066;
}

.btn-custom01:active:focus {
  background-color: #333333;
  border-color: #ff0066;
  color: #ff0066;
}

.btn-custom01:hover,
.btn-custom01:focus {
  background-color: #3b3b3b;
  border-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the visited selector https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp
 `btn:visited {}`